# PHP foreach() outputs only the last item of an array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

Sequel to my previous post, my intention was only to keep my question straight to the point and short, but obviously and for the sake of clarity, it's best I include all the modules involved.

I'm working on a CodeIgniter project that requires users to provide multiple options with the help of an input post array like the one shown in the view below:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)" id="add_stock">
   <div class="stock">
      <div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-4">
           <input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="Name of item" class="form-control item" id="item" />
           <span class="item_err"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-4">
           <input type="text" name="unit[]" list="units" placeholder="Enter unit of measurement" class="form-control unit" id="unit" />
           <datalist id="units">
              <option>cube</option>
              <option>cup</option>
           </datalist>
           <span class="unit_err"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <input type="text" onfocus="(this.type='number')"  name="quantity[]" placeholder="Enter quantity" class="form-control quantity" id="quantity" />
            <span class="quantity_err"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-1">
             <button class="btn btn-primary add-more-stock" title="Add more item" style ="height:33px;margin-top: ;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
     <div class="form-group msg"></div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <button class="btn btn-primary add-stock text-uppercase"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> add stock</button>
     </div>
 </form>
```

I have a jQuery code that appends additional input fields as shown below:

```
    var max_fields = 20; // maximun inputs allowed
    var items = $('.stock');
    var x = 1;
    $('.add-more-stock').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (x < max_fields) {
        x++;
        $('.stock').append('<div><div class="form-group col-md-4"><input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="Name of item" class="form-control item" id="item" /><span class="item_err"></span></div><div class="form-group col-md-4"><input type="text" name="unit[]" list="units" placeholder="Enter unit of measurement" class="form-control unit" id="unit" /><datalist id="units"><option>cube</option><option>cup</option><option>mudu</option><option>bags</option><option>carton</option> <option>crate</option> <option>bottle</option></datalist><span class="unit_err"></span></div><div class="form-group col-md-3"><input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="Enter quantity" class="form-control quantity" id="quantity" /> <span class="quantity_err"></span></div><button class="btn btn-danger remove-stock col-sm-1" title="Remove item" style ="height:33px;margin-bottom: -1px; width: 40px;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></div>');
      }else{
        $('.input-alert').attr('class','alert alert-warning').html('<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> You have reached the maximun of 20 input fields reached.').show();
      }
    })

    
    $(items).on('click','.remove-stock',function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('div').remove();
      $('.input-alert').hide();
    })
```

And here is the complete jQuery code that passes the contents of the text fields to my controller:

```
   $('.add-stock').click(function (e) {

      var item = new Array();
      var unit = new Array();
      var quantity = new Array();

      var item_arr = $("input[name^='item']");

      var unit_arr = $("input[name^='unit']");

      var quantity_arr = $("input[name^='quantity']");

      item_arr.each(function(){
        item.push(this.value);
      }); 

      unit_arr.each(function(){
        unit.push(this.value);
      }); 

      quantity_arr.each(function(){
        quantity.push(this.value);
      });

      $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url()?>admin/add_stock',
        type: 'post',
        data: {item:item,unit:unit,quantity:quantity},
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
          $(".add-stock").html("<img src='<?php echo base_url()?>asset/images/a.gif' width='20' height='20'/> proceesing...");
        },
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.success) {
            $('.add-stock').html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></> add stock');
            $('.msg').attr('class', 'alert alert-success').html('<i class="fa fa-check"></> '+data.msg).delay(5000).fadeOut();
          }else if (data.error) {
            if (data.unit) {
              $('.add-stock').html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></> add stock');
              $('.unit_err').attr('class', 'text-danger').html(data.unit).delay(5000).fadeOut();
            }else if (data.item) {
              $('.add-stock').html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></> add stock');
              $('.item_err').attr('class', 'text-danger').html(data.item).delay(5000).fadeOut();
            }else if (data.quantity) {
              $('.add-stock').html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></> add stock');
              $('.quantity_err').attr('class', 'text-danger').html(data.quantity).delay(5000).fadeOut();
            }else if (data.failed) {
              $('.add-stock').html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></> add stock');
              $('.msg').attr('class', 'alert alert-danger').html('<i class="fa fa-times"></> could not procees request...').delay(5000).fadeOut();
            }
          }
        },
        error: function () {
          $('add-stock').html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></> add stock');
          $('.msg').attr('class', 'alert alert-warning').html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></> something went wrong.').delay(5000).fadeOut();
        }
      })
    })
```

So, am trying to get the options in order to store them in separate rows and respective columns with the help of PHP (CodeIgniter)...

So far, this is my full controller

```
    function add_stock()
    {
        
            $items = $_POST['item'];
            $units = $_POST['unit'];
            $quantitys = $_POST['quantity'];

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $stock['item'] = $item;
            }

            foreach ($units as $unit) {
                $stock['unit_of_measurement'] = $unit;
            }

            foreach ($quantitys as $quantity) {
                $stock['quantity'] = $quantity;
            }
            $stock['added_by'] = 'Admin';
            
            
            $stmt = $this->db->insert('stocks', $stock);

            if($stmt):
                $array = array('success' => true, 'msg'=>'Item has been successfully added to store');
            else:
                $array = array('error' => true, 'failed'=>true);
            endif;
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
```

Now, the problem is that, instead of getting the whole contents of the array displayed, only the last content is outputted i.e. if the contents of $array are ['a','b'], instead of displaying a,b the foreach() loop only displays b.

But when I echo $items, $units or $quantitys itself, the contents of the array gets displayed.

So, please, how can I get all the contents of the array and insert them into different rows?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem starts in your form, and then gets worse in your controller.

The specific issue in your controller is this:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
   $stock['item'] = $item;
}
```

You're iterating over the `$items` array, but overwriting the value of `$stock['item']` on each iteration. Only the last value is stored.

To fix this you need to do a number of things:

First, use array indexes in your form names. This allows you to extract the corresponding values in the arrays you receive in `$_POST`

In your HTML use `name="item[0]"`, `name="unit[0]"`, `name="quantity[0]"` in your `<input>` fields.

Then, in the Javascript code that adds new rows, increment the index for each new row. You already have a counter that you can use for this = `x`.

```
'<input type="text" name="item[' + x + ']" placeholder="Name of item" class="form-control item" id="item" />'
```

(I haven't reproduced the whole line - you get the idea)

These changes should give you three arrays in your input that you can iterate over in a single loop:

```
$items = $_POST['item'];
$units = $_POST['unit'];
$qtys = $_POST['quantity'];

for($i=0;$i<count($items); $i++) {
    $item = $items[$i];
    $unit = $units[$i];
    $qty = $qtys[$i];

    // Do your database update here with these three variables
```

}

Purists will note that you could use the array elements directly. I agree, but this is clearer.

You could extend the indexes to give you a two dimensional array:

```
name="products[0]['item']" 
name="products[0]['unit']"
name="products[0]['quantity']"
```

(and corresponding changes to use `x`in Javascript)

Then iterate over $_POST]['products']:

```
foreach($_POST['products'] as $product) {
     $unit = $product['unit'];
     ...
}
```